# Convert HTML to JSON or another usefull object?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I write a small tool for websites, I get HTML code with `file_get_contents()`, needed is to convert this code into a object like JSON or Array because I want to get some parts like content from `<title>` tag or to check if any `<h1>` exist...

I'm interessted to know what is the best method to parse this html code?

Comment: This HTML is a full, well formed HTML document or some partial? If full,  You could try using SimpleXML http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: tool suggestions are off-topic

Comment: @RafalKozlowski I want to convert full html code/response to a object, it can be also XML, is simplexmlelement ok for this work?